# Preparing text data for SciKit classification

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn

I'm trying to load my data into scikit-learn to train a bunch of classifiers. Instead of having one file per document and one folder per category as the standard seems to be, my data looks like the following (semicolon-delimited csv) :

```
train_data.csv :
    label; sentence
    cat0 ; data
    cat0 ; data
    cat1 ; data
    cat2 ; data
    ...
```

Therefore I can't use load_files and I'm a bit lost when it comes to extracting the features in a relevant manner.

Should I separate my data into one file per category, each containing all the relevant documents, and in a named folder, or can I import from my csv as it is? Having one file per document seems like a big waste of time/resources.

Here's the code I'm working on, but obviously missing a step :)

```
def create_training_tfidf():
    docs = []
    targets = []
    with open("sets/test2.csv", "r") as sentences_file:
        reader = csv.reader(sentences_file, delimiter=';')
        reader.next()
        for row in reader:
            docs.append(row[1])
            targets.append(row[0])

    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,3), min_df = 0, stop_words = 'english')
    tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(docs)
    print tf.get_feature_names()
    return tfidf_matrix, targets
```

Comment: As a starting point, what code have to tried to load your CSV with? Are you using Pandas or something? There are a few ways that you should be able to solve your task.

Comment: I haven't tried Pandas, I thought that basic csv/collections would do the trick, I added the piece of code I'm working on at the moment

Comment: The code looks ok to me. You read your csv and got the tf-Idf features along with the labels... What's missing in there? Apart from that your csv file looks to me like a more convenient format than having one folder for each category, as long as the documents are of reasonable size.

Comment: yep, now it's working, I was being stupid and had 0 and 1 backwards :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is get your data into two matrices: features and actual targets. How you parse and retrieve this data is entirely up to you.

I have used 'pandas' before to parse data.

Also, from what I remember there is some function (might not be in 'pandas') that you can use to parse using delimiters.

Hope this helps a bit